# Blender mesh data structure

Tags: blender, mesh, modeling

Does anyone know what data structure blender is using? Like Half-Edge / Winged Edge / Shared Vertext / Directed Edge etc.

I should prepare a presentation for my university about different data structures. As we're using Blender, I think, I should at least know that about Blender. I also did google it, but it seems like no one knows anything about that.

Comment: You should find some of the main blender devs on IRC `#blendercoders` would be the ones to answer that, or use the source... you should find the main data structures in [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenkernel/) and bmesh, which is used for the edit mode mesh data [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/bmesh/).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but the data structure used draws from the "Radial Edge Structure"

Documented here: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Modeling/BMesh/Design